# How to use std::function using variadic template

Tags: c++, stl

There is a [template for constructing `std::function`:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

I have not figured out how to invoke it. (VC++, if that matters.)

Question: How can I use `std::function` with a variadic list without using `std::bind`?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using vfunc = std::function<void()>;
using namespace std; // I know, I know.

template<class F, class... Args>
void
run(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    vfunc fn = bind(forward<F>(f), forward<Args>(args)...); //OK
    //vfunc fn = vfunc(forward<F>(f), forward<Args>(args)...); // COMPILER ERROR
    fn();
}

void foo(int x) {
    cout << x << " skidoo\n";
}
int main() {
    run(foo, 23);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Because you can implement `run` without using `std::function` just do `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: @ChisDrew - It's for a thread-pool class. I need a `std;:function<void()>` for the worker threads. Thank you for your concern. :-)

Comment: @xskxzr - I do not understand your comment and question. The template to which I refer is on the cppreference page that's clickable in the question. Do you know the answer to my question? Is it not possible, and if not, why not?

Comment: What about using a lambda?

Comment: @xskxzr - Lamda's have no utterable type. Really folks,I appreciate that you are trying to help, but the real application requires an `std::function<void()>`. Really it does.  The question is only how to forego the `bind` if possible - as much out of curiosity as anything.

Comment: I mean something like `vfunc fn = []{f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);};`

Comment: @xskxar - Yes, that would work, but it's hardly an improvement on using `bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a template for constructing `std::function`.
>
> ```
> template< class R, class... Args >
> class function<R(Args...)>;
> ```

That's not what that declaration means. It's not declaring a *constructor* or a "template for constructing" anything; it's a specialization for the template class `std::function`. The specialization is the only definition of std::function; the base template is never defined. I think the point of this has something to do with using a function signature in the template declaration. That is, being able to use the template via function rather than as function.

You want to take a callable object and some number of values and create a new callable object that stores those values, which has an `operator()` overload that calls the given function with those values. `std::function` does not do that; it has no constructors for doing so.

This is *exactly* what `std::bind` is for. Basically, your code is fine as is: storing the result of `bind` within `function` is entirely valid.

Comment: What is that template for for?

Comment: I need a function object that has a well-known type, hence `std::function`. I think I am hearing that I must do the `bind` first, although I am still puzzled by that template from cppreference.com

Comment: The specialization is the *only* definition of `std::function`; the base template is never defined. I think the point of this has something to do with using a function signature in the template declaration. That is, being able to use the template via `function<void(int)>` rather than as `function<void, int>`.

Comment: I guess I do not understand these things well enough to, uh, understand. I am just going to use `bind` and not worry my pretty little head about it.  The  thread pool is working just fine that way, and it is blazing fast.

Comment: @JiveDadson: Think of it just as "a thing people have to do in C++ to make it work right". Deep metaprogramming has all kinds of esoteric issues with it. But you don't have to understand it to *use* it.

Comment: Tell me about it. I delved into the Dinkum implementation - always an adventure. What a hot mess!  It is full of MACROs for deduction guides and other imponderables. It seems to depend on the function object having an `operator()`.  As usual, I ran away in horror.  As I said, the thread pool is working great, and whoa is it fast.

Comment: Ah. Light dawns over Dunderhead!

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can just wrap the function in a lambda and construct your `std::function` from it.

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void run(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    auto fn = vfunc{
        [=]() mutable {
            std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };

    fn(); // fn is of type std::function<void()>
}
```

I made the lambda mutable so `std::forward` will not silently not move.

Note however that the `[=]` capture will copy everything. To support move only types, you can use a tuple:

```
[f = std::forward<F>(f), args = std::tuple{std::forward<Args>(args)...}]() mutable {
    std::apply(std::forward<F>(f), std::move(args));
}
```

In C++20, this becomes easier:

```
[f = std::forward<F>(f), ...args = std::forward<Args>(args)...]() mutable {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, this does not answer the question. A lambda has no advantage over bind that I can see. The use of `std::functions` is A REQUIREMENT of the problem. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @JiveDadson please look more carefully. I assign the lambda into an `std::function` of the type you defined `vfunc`. As far as I know, it respects the specified requirements.

Comment: @JiveDadson this shows exactly how to construct a`std::function` from a callable. Is there something I can clarify?

Comment: I think the confusion is due to my confusion. Bind and lambda both work just fine. I thought there was a way to get the `std::function` without a `bind` or `lambda` or other wrap'em up thing. Apparently I was wrong.